# Cannot convert from autobuggi.models.carcategory to autobuggi.repository.autobuggi.carcategory

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

This is my CategoryRepository Class file

```
namespace AutoBuggi.Repository
{
    public class CategoryRepository
    {
        //private object dbCategory;

        public Guid SaveCategory(Models.CarCategory model)
        {
            try
            {
                using (var dbcontext = new AutoBuggiEntities())
                {
                    var dbCategory = new Models.CarCategory()
                    {
                        Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                        CategoryId = model.CategoryId,
                        VariantName = model.VariantName
                    };
                    dbcontext.CarCategories.Add(dbCategory);
                    dbcontext.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
            catch(Exception)
            {

            }

            return Guid.Empty;

        }


    }
}
```

Comment: You have two CarCategory classes. One is defined in the autobuggi.models namespace and one in the autobuggi.repository.autobuggi. The dbContext wants a class from the latest namespace not from the first and you build an instance of the class from the model namespace

Comment: _var dbCategory = new Autobuggi.Repository.Autobuggi.CarCategory();_

Comment: Thank you Brother.

Comment: I want to return a CategoryId but it's showing error as  'object' does not contain a definition for 'CategoryId' and no extension method 'CategoryId' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)